# PHP and SQL, How to print multiple columns in the output

Tags: php, sql

i need help for my php script:

This is my index.php:

```js
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$db_hostname = '127.0.0.1';
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = 'password';
$db_database = 'mydatabase';


    $connect = mysqli_connect("$db_hostname","$db_username","$db_password");

    if (!$connect){

           die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
        
        }

    
    mysqli_select_db($connect, $db_database) or die ("could not find db");


    $output ='';



    if (isset ($_POST['search'])){

     $search = $_POST['search'];

   }


    $query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die("could not search");

    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    
    if($count == 0){

     $output = 'There was no search results !';

   }

    
    else{

         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
         $fname = $row['email'];
         $output .='<div> '.$fname.'</div>';}

        }  


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset=utf-8" />
      <title>Lookup</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" placeholder="search" name="search">
<input type="submit" value=">>"/>

</form>



<?php

print("$output"); 

?>

  </body>
</html>
```

- So the script works and its return me email from email column where my string is found.
- But i have another question, i have another column beside my email column named location, and every email correspond to a location value. So i want to see 2 columns on my OUTPUT.

This is example an of my columns:

`| email          |     location |`

`| john@gmail.com  |     Chicago |`

`| mike@gmail.com  |     Mexico  |`

---

- So this is what result i actually see on my index.php:
  `john@gmail.com
  mike@gmail.com
  donald@gmail.com
  roberto@gmail.com`

---

- And this is what i want to see:
  `john@gmail.com Tokyo
  mike@gmail.com London
  donald@gmail.com Paris
  roberto@gmail.com New-York`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `$row['location']`

Answer (score 3):

You're actually pretty close to what you want already. The key is in your `while` loop.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $fname = $row['email'];
    $loc   = $row['location'];
    $output .='<div>' . $fname . ' ' . $loc . '</div>';
}
```

The `$row` variable will contain an entry for every column you select in your query. You're using a `select *` in your query, so you may or may not realize all that's in there. If you want to see the contents, you might find `var_dump($row);` to be helpful for testing.

Comment: use `$row['location];` as `$row['location'];` see single quote missing

Answer (score 1):

Your else part should be:-

```
else{

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
     $fname_location = $row['email']."  ".$row['location'];
     $output .='<div> '.$fname_location .'</div>';}

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this part:

```
else{

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
     $fname = $row['email'];
     $output .='<div> '.$fname.'</div>';}

    }
```

To this:

```
else{

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
     $fname = $row['email'];
     $ulocation = $row['location '];
     $output .='<div> '.$fname . ' ' . $ulocation.'</div>';}

    }
```

Comment: missing dot `.` between php variables in output variable

Answer (score 0):

Set another variable `$location` to receive the location data from db just like you set the `$fname`

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
     $fname = $row['email'];
     $location = $row['location'];
     $output .='<div> '.$fname . ' ' . $location.'</div>';
 }
```